# Unable to connect to Kafka Broker on Hortonworks Sandbox (HDP 2.6) from my Windows Host Machine on Port 6667

Tags: apache-kafka, vmware, hortonworks-sandbox

I have downloaded Hortonworks Sandbox (IP: 192.179.144.XXX) on my Windows 10 laptop. I have the HDP Sandbox running on VMWare.

Below is my sandbox information:

```
Created on: 19_04_2017_19_09_16 for 
Hadoop stack version:  Hadoop 2.7.3.2.6.0.3-8 
Ambari Version: 2.5.0.5-1 
Ambari Hash: 0b5e975972e7a0b265e87b2e38eefde9039ef44c 
Ambari build:  Release : 1 
Java version:  1.8.0_121 
OS Version:  CentOS release 6.9 (Final)</code>
```

My goal is to be able to connect to Kafka (HDP Sandbox) from Java IntelliJ SDK based out of my Windows host machine.

So far, I have tried the following in order to be able to access HDP Kafka from my host machine via Java and/or Kafka tool 1.0, but been unsuccessful.

1. Updated the Network-Atapter to 'Host Only' in my VMware settings.
2. Opened, Kafka broker, port number 6667 by adding the port number to the 'start_sandbox.sh' file. Leveraged the following article: http://tlxu.blogspot.com/2016/12/add-ports-mapping-to-hdp-25-vmware.html

   `2.1 Below are the steps taken to "open" the port 6667 - 
   2.1.1) login to the Sandbox VM (actual docker container) 
   2.1.2) Disable sandbox.service: $ systemctl disable sandbox.service 
   2.1.3) Reboot the VM: $ init 6 
   2.1.4) Modify sandbox start script: $ vi /root/start_scripts/start_sandbox.sh 
   2.1.5) Added "-p 6667:6667 \" after "-p 2222:22 \" 
   2.1.6) save and exit. 
   2.1.7) Delete existing sandbox container: $ docker rm sandbox 
   2.1.8) Enable sandbox.service: systemctl enable sandbox.service 
   2.1.9) Reboot the VM: $ init 6 
   2.1.10) Verify new ports: $ docker ps | grep 6667 
   2.1.11) Received the following output - 0.0.0.0:6667->6667/tcp`
3. However, when I open chrome on my laptop and try to connect to: http://192.179.144.XXX:6667, I receive the following error:

   `This site can’t be reached The webpage at http://192.179.144.XXX:6667/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a web address. ERR_UNSAFE_PORT`
4. I also tried 'logging' and 'telnetting' on the sandbox using "Putty" with following credentials: root@192.179.144.XXX and port: 6667. I receive the following error:

   `Network Error: software caused connection abort`
5. Within the sandbox I ran the following command to check if the port is open inside the sandbox. I don't know what the output means, though.

   `[root@sandbox ~]# netstat -tnlpa | grep 6667
   [root@sandbox ~]#`
6. Kafka properties in "Kafka Broker" section in Ambari has the following properties:

   `Kafka broker host: sandbox.hortonworks.com
   zookeeper.connect: sandbox.hortonworks.com:2181
   listeners: PLAINTEXT://localhost:6667`

   *(Please note: I also tried changing 'localhost' to '0.0.0.0', and my kafka-console-consumer and kafka-console-produer failed. Received "LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE" error.)*
7. Within Kafka properties in Ambari, I logged in as an Admin and added the following properties to the "Custom Kafka-broker"

   `advertised.port=6667
   advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://sandbox.hortonworks.com:6667
   advertised.host.name=192.179.144.XXX`

*I am unable to move forward, and I would really appreciate if anyone could help out on:* 
1.) Is my port open? If not, how else can I open the port?
2.) Any additional changes I need to make with Kafka settings, that would let the Java IDE on my Windows to connect to Kafka (dependent on issue #1)?

Comment: No, the port is closed. You will have to look at the logs to find out why. Try `systemctl status sandbox.service`.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is not an HTTP service. Chrome, or browser, will not connect.

Kafka is not an SSH program. Putty, or other, will be connect.

You need to verify connection using `kafka-console-*` tools from windows

---

```
listeners: PLAINTEXT://localhost:6667
```

Should be the following for Kafka to listen externally of the sandbox

```
 listeners: PLAINTEXT://:6667
```

Then, I don't know about Host Only or NAT settings, but you shouldn't need to touch those if you setup port forwarding in the VM settings.

---

```
advertised.host.name
```

Should not need to be changed in Ambari, but if you did, then set it to the sandbox hostname

---

If you don't need Hadoop and all the other stuff in HDP, I suggest getting the HDF sandbox, or just using Docker for Windows and using the Kafka containers on DockerHub